# Can PIN lock be disabled/enabled via Secure Settings with full device encryption?

Tags: encryption

I use Tasker and Secure Settings to enable/disable PIN lock based upon connections to select WiFi and Bluetooth devices.  I've recently unlocked the bootloader and rooted my phone.  I would like to use full device encryption.  Will I still be able to toggle the PIN lock?